# Logistic Regression not quite working

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, libsvm, scikit-learn, scipy

I'm playing around with logistic regression (using scikit-learn, which uses liblinear)

I created some example data sets, and it often works well. Since I created the data sets, I already know the optimal bounds, and a 100% correct linear classifier is possible.

Fairly often (~1 in 10) the predicted bound is off (see figure). It seems obvious to me that moving the bound a fraction higher would be better. What might have gone wrong? Are there parameters I should try changing, or better algorithms to use?

[image: example of failing]

Comment: What is the frequency of the classes and what cut-off do you use? Try setting it a bit higher if one class is more frequent.

Comment: Thanks - didn't think of the frequencies of classes. Adjusted for that and it works. Also, l1 penalization works much better than l2, although I don't understand why...

Comment: What formula are you using to compute that linear separator?  (I presume you are regressing the symbol--which has only two classes--against the $x$ and $y$ coordinates in the plot and then using the estimated coefficients to identify the line.)

Comment: Hi whuber - yes that's exactly what I did